# In SQL can a table have both primary keys + composite keys?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, can a table have primary key on 1 column and then composite keys on other two or more columns?

Comment: You can only have 1 primary key per table. That key can be on one or more combined columns assuming the column type allows for it to be included as a primary key.

Comment: Just to be clear - the primary key can be composed of any number of columns, not just 1. And since you are asking, you can only have one clustered index. Do not assume that the primary key must (or should) be the clustered index. Nor is the clustered index required to be unique.

Comment: Maybe it is best to lookup definitions for these terms: Primary Key, Clustered Key, Unique Index, and Unique Constraint. That should clarify it a little I believe. (I am assuming you are not asking about table relations so Foreign Key is not applicable to your question even though it has the word Key in the name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

A table can have more than one Key, and a Key has one or more key columns.

In SQL Server you create a Key with any of a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, a PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT, or a UNIQUE INDEX.  A table can at most one PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT, but can have any number of UNIQUE CONSTRAINTs or UNIQUE INDEXs.

So yes, a table can have a PRIMARY KEY on one column, and a composite UNIQUE INDEX or UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.

Comment: We standardize on unique indexes because, while the underlying implementation is the same as a unique constraint, they allow for additional features such as filters, include columns, compression, etc.

Comment: We can have primary key composed of more than 1 columns and in b/w that we can set 1 column as Identity and auto increment and this is how it will also be managed with logic where 1 key should be auto generated

Comment: @Ali If you are using an IDENTITY column as your primary key, why do you need to add additional columns to it? An additional column can't make a unique number any more unique. What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish? What is `b/w`?

Comment: I am trying to add additional columns as key part so SQL change tracking can track it as well since for deleted row it only give primary keys and I can use that additional key for processing where I need

Comment: there are other workarounds but I have very short time and I not want to use them right now

Comment: The only time you should have an IDENTITY as part of a composite primary key is where you are modeling a "child collection" or "weak entity".  EG `OrderItem(OrderID,OrderItemID)`, where OrderID is a Foreign Key, and OrderItemID is generated by an IDENTITY/SEQUENCE.

Comment: And I want to caution that "doing it fast" is never better than "doing it right"...

Comment: In Change Tracking you typically have to join back to the target table to get any other columns.  It's not advisable to change your PK to avoid that join.

Comment: yes but my scenarios are that target and source tables are not same and I need deleted column must which I can only fetch from source table and this is why I am adding two keys in source table so I can retrieve them